drf-spectacular hide Schemas from components in Swagger UI
In my Swagger UI, I'm trying to hide the Schemas section from components:

I'm using drf-spectacular and I didn't find anything relating to Schemas in the Swagger Configuration.
I tried removing schemas from the JSON response:
from drf_spectacular.views import SpectacularJSONAPIView

class CustomJSONAPIView(SpectacularJSONAPIView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)
        del response.data["components"]["schemas"]
        return response

Which works, but corrupts rest of the Swagger functionality. Is it possible to simply hide this Schemas component without breaking rest of Swagger?

Swagger UI option that hides the "Schemas" section is defaultModelsExpandDepth: -1 (note: plural "Models"). Check if drf-spectacular exposes this option.
